# Initializing the Year of the Calendar to be 1965 instead of 2020

Tags: angular, visual-studio, calendar

so I am stuck with this part. I am trying to change the initial calendar year from 2020 to 1965 so only people of the age of 55 or higher can sign up. I am confident that this change occurs in the HTML file, any advice ?

I also have the dates disabled from 1965 on wards so users cant sign up unless you're 55.

Here is part of my HTML code. **Calendar in HTML file**

```
  <div>
        <nz-form-label class="form-label"
        [nzNoColon]="true">date of birth*</nz-form-label>
        <nz-date-picker nzPlaceholder="Select a date"
                        nzFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate"
                        formControlName="age"


        ></nz-date-picker>
    </div>
```

[image: Trying to change 2020 to 1965]

Answer (score 0):

did you try width `[nzDefaultPickerValue]`.
It can get a `Date` or a `Date[]`. So you can use to set a default date using the today date.